# Compare elements in large list of data

Tags: python, bigdata

I've got the question on interview by python recently. The question was:

> we have a large list of pictures in python(as I understood we simply read their content, and then got list of their contents), `[...]`, this list will occupy 1gb of RAM e.g. What is the best way to compare them(do pictures the same)?
>   I answered that we can separate this list into several lists and then compare elements in them.

But I got answer that: "it is wrong".
So my question the same what is the best way here to compare them?

Currently I think maybe use python's sets and compare lengths of source list and set?

Comment: Compare how? Whether there are duplicates? Whether pictures are the same w.r.t. rotation/reflection/resizing? Whether they show similar objects? The answer could be anywhere from "calculate and compare hashes" to "look for a good image library".

Comment: How are you going to judge any answers you get since you don't know what the correct one is?

Comment: What purpose would be served by separating the list into several smaller lists?

Comment: @tobias_k duplicates

Comment: @martineau I just got abstract question sorry for, but it was typical interview , as I decided with not quite trained specialist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the list contains the raw byte strings of the image contents, one quick and dirty way to weed out possible duplicates is to compare the *lengths* of the byte strings.  Two pictures with unequal length byte strings cannot be duplicates.

Then, for each group of pictures with equal length byte strings, hash the byte strings and compare those.  If the hashes are equal then the pictures are duplicates, otherwise they're not.  (For extra speed, don't bother hashing if there are only two byte strings in a group; just compare the strings directly byte-by-byte.)

Comment: ok, thank you, but what would be if I would get new question, "oh it's too long to compare elements one by one, how to compare them faster e.g.?"

Comment: That's why you compare the _lengths_ first.  Did you not read my answer?

Comment: Lengths are just another hash. Hashing is the way to go but not sure specifically using lengths is best.

Comment: @ReutSharabani The lengths are already computed, so that would be a very fast first pass.

Comment: well, comparing the middle byte is also very fast and could prove faster. The answer "use hash" is right. The suggestion to use lengths as hashes specifically could be right... Could be wrong as well.

Comment: I think this answer is missing one crucial bit of information, that's probably obvious for you, but maybe not for OP: That the length or hashes should not be used to compare the images pairwise, but as a key in some hashmap/dictionary, mapping hashes to lists of images having those hashes. Also, if two images have the same hash the are very likely, but not guaranteed to be equal, so you'd still have to compare all the pictures in the same-hash groups pairwise, byte by byte.